# How to store assets separately with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I am looking to replace Grunt and Gulp with Webpack. I like how it transpiles everything but what I can't figure out is how to keep css separated from `bundle.js`? It just squashes everything together.

What I want it to compile `sass` and output the results into some `application.css`.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done with the [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). It "pulls out" any string and puts it into a separate file. And CSS is just a JavaScript string in a webpack bundle.

Please be aware that you will loose SourceMaps support and HotCodeReplacement, since there are currently unsolved issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete config that will parse out any scss requires you might have and put them in their own css bundle.  It also transpiles jsx and url encodes images. The magic is in the sass loader which is run before the extract text loader `'css!sass'` If you're not using sass just change it to `css` to use the css loader.
 eg.

```
//your entry file.js
var stylesheet = require('../scss/yourstyle');
...

//webpack.config.js
//main webpack config
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    name: 'browser',
    target: 'web',
    entry: {
        main: './app/yourapp'
    },
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    resolve: {
        root: path.join(__dirname),
        modulesDirectories: ['app', 'images', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', 'gif']
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        console: true
    },
    output: {
        path: 'public/dist',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.[chunkhash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.[name].[chunkhash].css', {
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true // extract all css from async chunks as well
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            children: true, // extract common js from children
            async: true, // and aysnc chunks
            minChunks: 3 // where there are 3 or more and put commons into main.js
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css!sass')
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loader: 'url?limit=100000&hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]'
        }, {
            include: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        }, {
            include: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }]
    }

};
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a config. I was under the impression that webpack meant to have terse config files. Thanks, I'll test it.

Comment: hehe. webpack is like a wall of configs.